# Class<? extends ParentClas> as a method Parameters. How can I access child class getter/setter?

Tags: java, inheritance

So I have 2 classes that have 80% identical variables. So my solution is to create a parent class that holds similar variables and child classes to hold the distinct one. Then here is a problem, How do I access child variable getter/setter? Below is my pseudo code of the problem

```
public class Human {
    Integer age;
    Integer height;

    public Integer getAge() {return age;}

    public Integer getHeight() {return height;}
}

public class Child extends Human { 
    String school;

    public String getSchool() {
        return school;
    }
}

public class Adult extends Human { 
    String job;

    public String getJob() {
        return job;
    }
}

public printDistinct(Class<? extends Human> human) {
    Integer takeId = human.getAge() // notwork
    String getString = human.getJob() //how?
}
```

Comment: Please post the error that you are getting.

Comment: `public <T extends Human> void printDistinct(T human) { Integer takeId = human.getAge();   }`

Comment: Note that this parameter, `Class<? extends Human> human` is of type Class, not of type Human or child of Human. As per the second duplicate, if you substitute `public printDistinct(List<? extends Human> human) {`, you'd see immediately that the parameter is not a Human object but rather a List of objects that are Humans or children of Human.